# "TypeError: this.types is not a function" when using "vuex-orm-decorators"

Tags: vuex-orm

I'm trying to use the npm package 'vuex-orm-decorators' from https://github.com/scotley/vuex-orm-decorators#readme

When I try to insert into the DB, I get the error `TypeError: this.types is not a function`

Entity looks like this

```
import { Model } from "@vuex-orm/core";
import { NumberField, OrmModel, StringField } from "vuex-orm-decorators";

@OrmModel("races")
export default class Race extends Model {
  @NumberField()
  public ID!: number;

  @StringField()
  public Name!: string;
}
```

store looks like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import { ORMDatabase } from "vuex-orm-decorators";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  .
  .
  .
  plugins: [ORMDatabase.install()]
});
```

Also, maybe this is a clue.... in Vuex-Orm, this.setters is returning a value, but this.setters('all') is returning undefined.

```
/**
 * Get all records.
 */
Model.all = function () {
   return this.getters('all')();
};
```

From seeing the undefined basic fields and functions, it seems like the vuex-orm database isn't getting set up correctly. Any ideas?

I tried to create a stackoverflow tag for vuex-orm-decorators, but I'm not quite at 1500 rep yet, so I just tagged it as vuex-orm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small bug in [vuex-orm-decorators](https://github.com/Scotley/vuex-orm-decorators) package in the implementation of the `types` function defined in Vuex-ORM [Single Table Inheritance](https://vuex-orm.github.io/vuex-orm/guide/model/single-table-inheritance.html#interacting-with-data) docs.

I've created a [fork](https://github.com/armaaar/vuex-orm-decorators) in which I fixed this simple problem and created a [pull request](https://github.com/Scotley/vuex-orm-decorators/pull/4) to update the original package.

Lastly, I've to point that from my tiny dive into this package that it isn't fully ready yet for table inheritance features built in Vuex-ORM but still is great for simple use cases.

Comment: Thanks for this fix Ahmed

Comment: Don't mention it. the pull request was merged so you can now use the package with no problem.